# Play framework Slick 3 how to disable H2 foreign key constraints by scala?

Tags: scala, h2, slick

I'm using Play framework 2.3 by Scala. For database management I'm using slick 3. I would like to temporally disable foreign key constraints for H2 database. I found it is possible in H2 by SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE. But I don't know how to set it by Scala in slick. Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain sqlu"SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE". Please see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/sql.html

Edit: This is the working code,

```
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Test extends App {

  def db = Database.forURL(
        url    = s"jdbc:h2:mem:test",
        driver = "org.h2.Driver"
  )

  def disableRefInt = {
      val result = db.run(sqlu"SET foreign_key_checks = 0 ");
      result onSuccess {
          case x => println("Done with the command" + x.toString());
      }
      result onFailure {
          case x => println("Not Done with the command" + x.toString());
      }
  }

}
```

For some reason "set referential_integrity false" is giving error while, "set foreign_key_checks=0" seems to be working fine.

Comment: There is compiler error. I tried as 

def testSet: DBIO[Unit] = {
  sqlu"SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE"
}

[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : slick.profile.SqlStreamingAction[slick.dbio.Effect,Vector[Int],Int]
[error]  required: slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api.DBIO[Unit]
[error]     (which expands to)  slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Unit,slick.dbio.NoStream,slick.dbio.Effect.All]
[error]     sqlu"SET REFERENTIAL_INTEGRITY FALSE"
[error]     ^

Also tried couple other variant. I couldn’t compile the code. Please advice me how to compile successfully in Scala on play.

Comment: sqlu return DBIO[Int]. please try with def testSet: DBIO[Int].